# M5強 meaning of 強

Tags: kanji

what does it stand for that　強? M5 is standing for magnitude 5, and 強 could mean "a less more than"?

周辺ではその後も、**M5強**の地震が続いた。

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, 「M5強」 is read 「マグニチュードごきょう」.

Answer (score 3):

It means 'a bit more than magnitude 5'. The alternative is M5弱, 'a bit under M5'.

Comment: Does it mean 地震の強度? Doesn't?

Comment: @QING I don't think so, if I understand your question. 'M5強' is short for 'M5より少し強い'.